# spring boot doesn't shows custom error pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, error-handling, customization

I added `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency to my project that using **spring boot 2.3.1.RELEASE** and placed `error.html` file inside `src/main/resources/templates` with name `error.html and other custom error pages inside` src/main/resources/templates/error` as you can see in below image:

[image: Custom error page files]

and add this configuration in application.yml:

```
server:
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false
```

and exclude `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration` by add `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})` into `Application` class.

But, unfortunately i see this below page when error occurs, for example for 404 error!

[image: 404 error page]

How can i solve this problem? i also googled for this but didn't find anything to help.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `WebServerFactoryCustomizer`:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addErrorPages(
                new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, "/403"),
                new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404"),
                new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/500"));
    }
}
```

And ErrorController:

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController {

    @GetMapping("/403")
    public String forbidden(Model model) {
        return "error/403";
    }

    @GetMapping("/404")
    public String notFound(Model model) {
        return "error/404";
    }

    @GetMapping("/500")
    public String internal(Model model) {
        return "error/500";
    }

    @GetMapping("/access-denied")
    public String accessDenied() {
        return "error/access-denied";
    }
}
```

I have the same structure and it works for me:

[image]

Example: [Customize the Error Messages](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-application-configuration#customize-the-error-messages)

PS: in mine `application.yml` i don't have any properties for error handling

Comment: With Spring boot 2.3 and JSP with Tiles - this was the only method that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to exclude `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration`.
Simply put error pages to these places.

see also:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling-custom-error-pages

Answer (score 0):

1. add this configuration in application.yml/application.properties:

   - server.error.path=/error
2. creat your error pages inder error path

   - error/400.html
   - error/500.html
   - error/error.html
3. create class implements ErrorController:

   @Controller

   public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController  {

   ```
   @RequestMapping("/error")
   ```

   public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {

   ```
    Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE); 

    if (status != null) {
        Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());

        if(statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
            return "/error/404";
        }
        else if(statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
            return "/error/500";
        }
    }
    return "/error/error";
   ```

   }

   }